# Getting sympy to simplify infinite sums containing piecewise functions

Tags: sympy

I am running the following in my jupyter-notebook.

```
from sympy import *

B = IndexedBase('B')
x, L = symbols('x L', real=True)
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
n = Idx(n, (0, oo))
Bn = Indexed('B', n)
m = Symbol('m', integer=True)

Sum(Piecewise((0, Ne(m, n)), (L, True))*B[n], (n, 0, oo)).doit()
```

The last expression should evaluate to $L B_n$. I have tried using `simplify`, `doit`, `limit` and `evalf` methods on it to without success. I also found more similar issues in [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8322) but couldn't taylor this to my specific problem.

I also tried fiddling around with the underlying assumptions for integer `m` but couldn't find anything suitable.

Is there any direct or indirect way to get `sympy` to simplify infinite sums containing piecewise functions?

Just as an aside this code below works:

```
p = Piecewise((1, n<5), (0, True))
Sum(p, (n, 1, oo)).evalf()
```